# Why is my avocado plant drooping and looking weak?

Tags: diagnosis, houseplants, avocado

[image]

I have an avocado plant I started from a pit, it’s around 1.5 years old. Around a month ago we put it in a bigger pot, because it stopped growing and we thought it needed more space. In these last days though it doesn’t look good. Its leaves look weak and lifeless. Any idea what the problem could be?

Comment: My first reaction to that photo was overwatered, meaning too often.  Is the medium moist throughout?  It might need to be allowed to dry out.  Large pots commonly cause their caretakers to drown the plant.

Comment: What size was the pot you transferred it from when compared to the one its in now? Did you cause any root damage when repotting?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers! The old pot is around two times smaller. Temperaturewise - I’m in Belgium and it’s quite cold these days, so there is definitely temperature change from a week ago. We have two other avocados which are still not potted - they are in water and they look fine. I won’t water it for a while and I hope it will get better

Comment: Did you manage to rescue this plant? I’ve just re-potted mine and it’s done the same thing 

Answer (score 4):

Drooping is a sign of 'wet feet', hence overwatering (see comment of @Evil Elf). If you water the plant too often, the soil can get too wet (even if the top layer seems fine). Try to feel finger deep before you water it again. Also use a pot with good drainage.

Too much watering causes the roots to rot, and causes deprivation of oxygen (roots use oxygen). Therefore it can not uptake enough water for enough pressure to hold up the leaves.

If the soil is not too wet it might also be a temperature problem, but first suspect is overwatering.

Comment: Agree.  After transplanting, the new soil does not have any roots in it and can remain damp for a really long time.  Therefore after transplanting you need to be very careful on watering, making sure that the soil is thoroughly dry.